# Initialize struct with single field

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have a struct:

```
 struct MY_TYPE {
      boolean flag;
      short int value;
      double stuff;
    };
```

I know I can intialize it by:

```
MY_TYPE a = { .flag = true, .value = 123, .stuff = 0.456 };
```

But, now I need to create a pointer variable `My_TYPE*` and I only want to initialize one field there? I tried e.g.:

```
MY_TYPE *a = {.value = 123};
```

But I get compiler error `"Designator in intializer for scalar type 'struct MY_TYPE *'"`.

Is it possible to initialize the struct with one field?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with one field. You cannot initialize a pointer with a 'struct initializer'.

Comment: So, do you mean it is impossible to do what I want or is there another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: It is impossible, but some syntactically very similar methods are shown in answers below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, you are mixing up `struct MY_TYPE` and typedef. The code posted won't work for that reason. You'll have to do like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
  bool flag;
  short int value;
  double stuff;
} MY_TYPE;
```

You can then use a pointer to a *compound literal*, to achieve what you are looking for:

```
MY_TYPE* ptr = &(MY_TYPE){ .flag = true, .value = 123, .stuff = 0.456 };
```

But please note that the compound literal will have local scope. If you wish to use these data past the end of the local scope, then you have to use a pointer to a statically or dynamically allocated variable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>   

struct MY_TYPE
{
    bool flag;
    short int value;
    double stuff;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct MY_TYPE *a = &(struct MY_TYPE){.value = 123};

    printf("%d\n", a->value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, if you first create an actual instance of the structure initialized the way you want, and then make the pointer point to that.

E.g.

```
struct MY_TYPE a = {.value = 123};
struct MY_TYPE *p = &a;
```

If you want to allocate a structure dynamically, then no it is not possible. Then you need to do it in two steps: Allocation; Followed by initialization:

```
struct MY_TYPE *p = calloc(1, sizeof *p);
p->value = 123;
```

The error you get have nothing to do with the initialization, but that you try to initialize a pointer with something that is not a pointer.